# Нужна помощь с JS

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm

```js
function arr_func()
{
    document.write(5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<input type="text" name="textbox_1" id="run">
<input type="button" name="button_1" value="Введите элементы массива" onclick="arr_func()">
</html>
```

Почему в браузере не выдает указанное значение после нажатия на клавишу.
Среда WebStorm. Новичок в JS. Тут все работает но не в WebStorm

Comment: а что выдает???

Comment: Добавьте код в пример в виде запускаемого кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: Разметку выдает. Когда делаю в блокноте все работает. Такое чувство что он не может связать Html файл и скрипт

Comment: Судя по всему функция находится в другом файле.

Comment: Можно ли как-то связать два файла JS и HTML ?

Comment: @Алексей они в одном штормовском проекте находятся?

Comment: @Алексей связать 2 файла можно через тег `<script>`в HTML - `<script src="relative/path/to/file.js">`. Если они лежат в одной директории, например, то `<script src="your_file.js">`. И WebStorm здесь совершенно не при чем, он Ваш код не исполняет и не связывает. Это браузер не может его найти, т.к. вы не написали соотв код в HTML

Comment: спасибо что объяснили

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно проверить html-код документа на валидность ([инструменты для проверки валидности html](http://validator.w3.org/)), у Вас объявлено два заголовка `<!DOCTYPE html>`, и не объявлен тег `<body>`. WebStorm подсвечивает желтым цветом ошибки. Также не видно где вы сделали подключение скрипта к документу. Вот пример рабочего кода:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Я новичок в HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="textbox_1" id="run">
<input type "button" name="button_1" value="Введите элементы массива" onclick="arr_func()">
</body>
<script>
  function arr_func(){
    alert(4);
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Или смотри на [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/YNMmpL)

Answer (score 0):

Если скрипт, в котором находится ваша функция, загружается в *.html* через `<script>` то *WebShtorm* увидит вашу функцию